# Xcode "folder already exists. Do you want to replace it?" - undo the replace

Tags: xcode, macos, unix

I accidentally hit "replace". How can I get my folder back? I don't see a .snapshot dir I'm used to from Unix, nor any other lucky guys that did the same in my google searches.

Comment: Can't you just restore it from your latest version control commit or Time Machine backup ?

Comment: No time machine. I didn't enable it due to small disk space.

Comment: No version control either ?

Comment: There is, only with initial commit of the files that replaced the folder. :(

Comment: Maybe it's time to invest in a disk for Time Machine backups and perhaps also try to get into the habit of committing more often ?

Comment: Committing what? It erased everything, including the version control files.

Comment: This is probably the lesson you need, everyone has to go through this once, that backups are a necessity. In the case of Mac Time Machine is easy and just works. Use a remote repository and push to it frequently, [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org) if free and provided a good service.

Comment: I understand I won't be able to find here someone familiar enough with Os X… Guys, you're trying to convince me to install your back-camera on my Lexus when I'm asking how to prevent it from opening the baggage every time I touch the driver door. So if we're talking about  lessons: A. It's not my fault, it could be a folder of pictures that was erased, just as it was source code folder and the guys that developed the above feature had had to think about it. B. If it was possible to scan the HD manually, I'd do that, but it's Macbook Air, so…

Comment: "I understand I won't be able to find here someone familiar enough with Os X": not true. Also A: It is your fault. B: OSX is unix, it has all the unix tools.

Comment: Sir, I sincerely mean every single word in the following: for your own good, I hope that once you have kids and once they do some  human mistake for which they'll be sued in a court, you'll do your best to find them a good lawyer and won't try to teach them a lesson.